# Django aggregate sum for each user

Tags: python, django, django-views, sum, django-aggregation

I'm creating a budget application and wanted to find the sum of each user who's signed in. Right now, I'm using function-based views and I sum up the expenses with `Post.objects.aggregate(sum = Sum('expense'))` The issue with this is it sums up everyone in the database but I wanted it to only sum up the expenses of the user that is currently signed in. In my model, I have an author field but I'm not sure how to go about summing only for the user currently signed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to get current user **expense**

`Post.objects.filter(author=request.user).aggregate(sum = Sum('expense'))`
this will return sum of current logged In user.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the sum for each user, with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

User.objects.annotate(total=Sum('post__expense'))
```

The `User` objects that arises from this `QuerySet` will contain the sum of the `expense`s of the related `post`s.

For the logged in user, you can calculate this with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

request.user.post_set.aggregate(total=Sum('expense'))['total'] or 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) and [annotate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) with [Sum()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#sum) to sum up **expense** column in `Post` model user by user as shown below. *You need to use `order_by('pk')` with `annotate()` otherwise values are printed in descending order:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

for obj in User.objects.all(): 
    print(Post.objects.filter(user=obj).aggregate(Sum('expense')))

for obj in User.objects.all(): 
    print(obj.post_set.aggregate(Sum('expense')))

qs = User.objects.annotate(Sum('post__expense')).order_by('pk')
for obj in qs:
    print(obj.post__expense__sum)
```

And, you can change the default key `expense__sum` and `post__expense` to `expenseSum` for **expense** column as shown below:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

for obj in User.objects.all():                    # ↓ Here
    print(Post.objects.filter(user=obj).aggregate(expenseSum=Sum('expense')))

for obj in User.objects.all():   # ↓ Here
    print(obj.post_set.aggregate(expenseSum=Sum('expense')))
                           # ↓ Here
qs = User.objects.annotate(expenseSum=Sum('post__expense')).order_by('pk')
for obj in qs: # ↓ Here
    print(obj.expenseSum)
```